# Are there any GUI man page editors are available?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, documentation, editor

I find the man page format extremely painful to write. Is there a GUI ([WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) or [WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM)) editor available to make this task easier? I'm hoping for an application that is to man pages as [Kompozer](http://kompozer.net/) is to web pages.

I have tried [gmanedit](http://packages.ubuntu.com/p/gmanedit) but have found that it is basically just a text editor with some easily available snippets - it is necessary to know the man page format to use it and the editing area is just a text widget.

While I'd prefer software that is in the official Ubuntu repositories, I am OK with using unsupported methods for installation such as PPAs or installing from source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible to author [man pages using DocBook](http://www.docbook.org/tdg/en/html/ch02.html#making-refentry) markup and use tools such as [docbook2x-man](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/docbook2x) to create troff output. There are some visual ("WYSIWYM"-style) editors available for editing DocBook markup. For example, the GPL-licensed [Syntext Serna Free](http://www.syntext.com/products/serna-free/):

[image: Screenshot of using Syntext Serna Free to edit a DocBook reference entry]

Also, [doclifter](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/doclifter) is a utility for converting man pages to DocBook.

Comment: Agreed, I write my man pages in docbook format. It's much more maintainable!

Comment: Docbook is the best format for creating documentation.  Once your Docbook file is completed, it can be converted to a multitude of formats.  XHTML, Man Pages, etc ...

Comment: Seems like a nice editor, but unfortunately it looks like there is no free version anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is an addendum to Jukka's suggestion of using docbook with the main reason why I like it other than it's much easier to write and deal with:

You can convert it to .pot files for more easy translation. For example, creating a .pot (language template):

`xml2po -o my_program.1.pot my_program.1.xml`

Then merging translated files (.po) back into a language specific docbook man page, in this case German:

`xml2po -p de.po my_program.xml > my_program.de.xml`

Answer (score 1):

[Grapse](http://www.roperzh.com/grapse/), an HTML5 webapp, was featured on Hacker News 2/3 of a year ago. It includes built-in preview and syntax highlighting.

Comment: It looks good but seems primarily for FreeBSD/OSX and doesn't format standard Linux man pages properly (e.g. loses paragraph spacing for options) even when switched to `AN` in top right of web page.

Answer (score 0):

There is one, [ManEdit](http://freshmeat.net/projects/manedit/). However, I don't know if its still active :(

Thanks!

Comment: I also found that one, it does seem to be abandoned and uses GTK 1.x!